# Droid Explorer app does not show hidden files

Tags: file-system, droid-explorer

Droid Explorer does not show hidden files. Some "root explorer" apps show hidden files, e.g. on `/data/data` etc., but Droid Explorer does not. Of course, ES File Explorer also does not show these, it shows only files which can be seen by the phone's own file explorer, but some "root explorers" show these.

How I can adjust Droid Explorer to show hidden files?

Comment: My original project was this, about 8 hour ago:
https://www.quora.com/I-have-Crypt7-files-of-my-girlfriends-WhatsApp-How-can-I-read-her-messages

I try copy open my whatsapp messages using any this-type way. Problem is, it is not any file explorer on Android which can 1) show and 2) copy any this type "hidden" file. Eg. this ES can show this "data" but is empty- even "show hidden files" is active. After several tests I found one "Root explorer" which can show this data/data/com.whatsapp etc, BUT copying is not possible.  
So- how to show Droid Explorer hidden files? Or any better explorer?

Comment: Try ES file explorer.

Comment: @VivekJi it was already mentioned that ES Explorer was tried, and that it shows "data" as empty. Both in the comment above yours, and in the original question.

Comment: Whatsapp messages aren't where you think they are. They are under `/sdcard/WhatsApp/Databases/` and are stored as encrypted `msgstore.db.crypt8` files. The mentioned folder path is not hidden in any way.

Answer (score 2):

I am the developer of this [Droid Explorer](https://github.com/camalot/droidexplorer) which does show hidden files.

If you are talking about this [Droid Explorer (by Asif Wani)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.asif.droid.explorer) then I can't help you, as I have nothing to do with that app. I would suggest you contact the developer of that app. His contact info is at the bottom of the link I posted.

I am going to assume you mean the App for Android Devices, not my application that runs on Windows...

In the settings of that application, there is the option:

[image]

Now, is your device rooted? Because you will not be able to see files in the `/data/apps/` or `/data/data/` if you don't have root. Root requires more than just a "root enabled" file explorer. And it will show "empty folders" if you do not have access to view the files. This is the case with all file explorers, including the one that I am the developer for.